# visual studio 2019 MemReAlloc

Tags: c++, memory-management

Apologies in advance if this turns out to be a stupid question...

I have picked up a very old piece of c++ code that references `MemReAlloc`. Does this function exist in current visual-studio/windows and if so how do I get access to it, or has it been replaced by new memory management functions?

I suspect it is a very old function from 16/32 bit days that is no longer supported.

Here's the offending code line:

```
EXTERNC HGLOBAL SYM_EXPORT WINAPI MemReAlloc (HGLOBAL hMem, DWORD dwBytes, UINT wFlags);
```

Regards
Kim

Comment: Microsoft doesn't have any documentation regarding a function called `MemReAlloc`, is this perhaps a wrapper for [`GlobalReAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalrealloc)?

Comment: I've never seen such a function before, but perhaps it should be replaced by [`HeapReAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heaprealloc)? Though to answer that for sure we'd need more info about how that function is used (e.g.: what arguments get passed to it, how the original memory was allocated, etc.)

Comment: I don't think it's a wrapper for GlobalReAlloc because there are numerous code snippets that use it as-is - searching for "MemReAlloc hotexamples" provides a bunch of github code snippets using it.    Maybe it should be replaced by HeapReAlloc but I guess that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @Kim looks like it was probably a macro wrapper for `GlobalRealloc` based on parameters and return type. Probably used with debugging output. `HeapRealloc` has different parameters and return type. I can't find anything on github that has exactly those parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help guys.  I have worked around the problem and resolved it by not using it :-)